# Finish a proof that every prime ideal of a ring is the contraction of a prime ideal in its formal power series

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Given a commutative ring $A$ with identity, and its formal power series ring $A[[x]]$, I am attempting to prove that every prime ideal of $A$ is the contraction of a prime ideal of $A[[x]]$. "Contraction" here means that if $I$ is an ideal of $A[[x]]$, the contraction of $I$ is $I \cap A$. (It doesn't mean that in general of course, but here that definition is equivalent thanks to the homomorphism in view.) By the previous part of the same exercise, I know that any maximal ideal of $A$ is generated by its contraction and $x$; I'm under the impression that the correct ideal to contract to get any prime ideal $P$ of $A$ is $Q=<P, x>$, the ideal of $A[[x]]$ generated by $P$ as a set and $x$. Clearly the contraction of $Q$ is $P$.

Where I am stuck is showing that $Q$ is prime. I know that if I have $fg \in Q$, where $f = \sum_{i=1}^∞ a_i x^i$ and $g = \sum_{i=1}^∞ b_i x^i$, then the mth coefficient of $fg$ is $\sum_{i=1}^m a_i b_{m-i}$, and in each case is necessarily an element of $P$, and obviously either $a_0$ or $b_0$ is in $P$ since $P$ is prime, but what is the best way to show that either f is in $Q$ or g is in $Q$? It seems like there is a risk that some coefficients of f might be in $P$ and some coefficients of g might be in $P$, but not all of either one. How can I be sure that isn't the case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Thanks to user115654 for pointing out an error in my previous answer)

Take the quotient ring $S = A[[x]]/(P,x)$. 
This is isomorphic to $A/P$ which is an integral domain since $P \in \operatorname{Spec} (A)$. So $(P,x)$ is a prime ideal of $A[[x]]$.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm allowed to use that theorem yet, since our class/the textbook hasn't covered modules yet. Also, I don't know what "faithfully flat" means.

Comment: Oh, in that case you maybe right. Kata t'alla ola kala?

Comment: Here is another idea: Try to prove that the quotient ring is an integral domain (see my edited answer).

Comment: Ah, that's actually much easier than what I was trying to do. And it more closely resembles what I did with the previous problem, too. Thanks!

Comment: @Manos: In general, $A[[x]]$ need not be a free $A$-module (in contrast to the polynomial ring $A[x]$). However, it is faithfully flat: in fact, this problem shows why! Your second approach is fine though.

Comment: @user115654: Thanks for pointing that out. I have asked a new question addressing this issue; you may want to answer it :)

Answer (score 2):

Note that your original approach can be finished easily:

As you noted, $a_0 \in P$ or $b_0 \in P$. Assume WLOG that $a_0 \in P$. To deduce that $f \in Q$, just note that $f = \sum_{i=0}^∞ a_i x^i$ (with indices starting at 0, not 1 as in the post) implies $f = a_0+x\sum_{i=1}^∞ a_i x^{i-1} \in P+(x)=Q$. Thus $Q$ is a prime ideal.